# nodemailer: cannot send pdf attachment

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I am just starting to learn javascript and I wanted to try building some small projects to get by feet wet.  As part of my first stab, I'm building a command line tool that will send out pdf attachments.  The script should send email with a pdf attachment based on an argument passed to the javascript.  I found some [code](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer#attachments) by googling around and tweaked it to meet my needs since I wanted to accept arguments from the command line.  I have included the code I'm using below.   It's supposed to take the pdf file name (test.pdf) as an argument and then send email to the designated recipients with that file attached. If I run it with my code as shown, I receive the email but the attachment received says "undefined.pdf" and cannot be opened.

It only works if I change the `path: '/home/user/attachments/' + myArgs[3],` line to be `path: '/home/user/attachments/test.pdf',` which ruins the point of the script because I don't want to hard code the file name in the "path" to attach the pdf file.
(For testing I am running the script from the same directory as the attachments \home\user\attachments.)

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?  I am a newbie to javascript so I am guessing I'm missing something obvious :]....

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var myArgs = process.argv.slice(2);
console.log('myArgs: ', myArgs);

// create reusable transporter object using SMTP transport
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'somebody@gmail.com',
        pass: 'secret'
    }
});

// NB! No need to recreate the transporter object. You can use
// the same transporter object for all e-mails

// setup e-mail data with unicode symbols

var mailOptions = {
    from: 'Somebody <somebody@gmail.com>', // sender address
    to: 'you@random.org, dude@blahblah.com', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Hello', // Subject line
    text: 'Hello world', // plaintext body
    html: '<b>Hello world</b>', // html body

    attachments: [
        {   // filename and content type is derived from path
            filename: myArgs[3],
            path: '/home/user/attachments/' + myArgs[3], 
            contentType: 'application/pdf'
        }
    ]   
};

// send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if(error){
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);

});
```

TIA,
Chris

Comment: What does the `console.log` line (line 3) print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us suppose, that you run such a command from the console:

```
node script.js file.pdf
```

`process.argv` returns an array containing the command line arguments. So, it would be:

```
process.argv[0] = 'node'
process.argv[1] = 'path/to/script.js'
process.argv[2] = 'file.pdf
```

By applying [`slice(2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), `process.argv` transforms into an array with just one element:

```
process.argv[0] = 'file.pdf';
```

So, it's most probably that you should change `myArgs[3]` to `myArgs[0]`. 
**Or** you should add more arguments so that `file` arg becomes the sixth one. For example:

```
node script.js to@email.com from@email.com email subject file.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks so much Lazarev! That was it.  Changed `myArgs[3]` to 'myArgs[0]' and it works now.

Comment: @LazarevAlexandr How do you account for allowing people upload their PDFs and attach? What would `path` be? It obviously wouldn't be the local filesystem path

Comment: @Growler I assume that you have a server running for that. Just create a route that will receive multipart data with required file, save the file to some tmp directory and send it with the help of nodemailer.